# what backend package does spacemacs use for layout managment?

Tags: package

I saw a neat demo of the spacemacs layout feature:
[demo of the spacemacs layout feature](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bwindow-management/spacemacs-layouts), and [another one](https://i.imgur.com/X5nYdlY.gif).

What package do they use to do that or another similar vanilla emacs package?

Comment: See the `packages.el` file under the same directory: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/layers/%2Bwindow-management/spacemacs-layouts/packages.el

Comment: I think it's something to do with 'perspective'-something package(s).

Comment: There is also integration for eyebrowse and even some code for combining both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend is [`persp-mode.el`](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el).